# Meteor Roles condition on render() in react

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I am trying to render the admin view based on Roles.
The problem is that I when I am authenticated, the render does not change.

I keep seeing:
Sign In
You are not admin

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import EasyTransition from 'react-easy-transition';
import {Meteor} from 'meteor/meteor';
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';
import { Roles } from 'meteor/alanning:roles';

import AccountsUI from './accounts_ui/login_buttons';
import Sidebar from './sidebar';



class AdminApp extends Component {

render() {
    if (this.props.isAdminUser) {
        return (
            <div>
                <EasyTransition path={location.pathname}
                                initialStyle={{opacity: 0}}
                                transition="opacity 0.3s ease-in"
                                finalStyle={{opacity: 1}}>
                    <Sidebar/>
                    {this.props.children}
                </EasyTransition>
            </div>
        )
    }

    if (!this.props.isAdminUser) {
        return (
            <div className="wrapper">
                <AccountsUI/>
                <p>You are not admin</p>
            </div>

        )
    }

}

};

export default createContainer(() => {
if (Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.userId(), ['superadmin'], 'backend')) {
   return {isAdminUser: true}
}
return {isAdminUser: false}
}, AdminApp)
```

I am logged in but the render is not changing, what am I missing here?

Comment: To my knowledge, your code *should* work. What happens if you do `Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.userId(), ['superadmin'], 'backend')` in the browser console once you are logged in? Are you absolutely sure you have the correct role, and that the roles field in your user document in published?

Comment: @Waiski the strange thing is then when I do that in the console then it works. The logic  seems to be working except that the component is not rerendering what it should render